Drawing Mask or Sunglasses to obscure face
Assalmualaikum,
Is it permissible to draw cartoon characters with no facial features (no eyes, mouth, nose, ears) but with head accessory? By this I mean something like the Power Rangers, where no facial feature is showing, but it is also not a plain head. Of course clothing will be modest and no vulgar depiction etc.
